# dimension of $U+W=$ ?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If U and W be the following subspaces of $R^4$..

U={(a,b,c,d): b+c+d=0}

W={(a,b,c,d):a+b=0,c=2d}

*What is dimension of U+W?*

Comment: Well, there are literally only 5 possibilities... surely you can tell us how you ruled out several of them.

Comment: Dimension of U and W can be figured by subtracting the number of restrictions from the number of unknowns. dimension of U intersection W can give the answer. But how can I figure it out?

Comment: Do you know Grassmann formula $$\dim (U+V) = \dim U + \dim V - \dim (U \cap V)$$?

Comment: Yes. I know that. But how will that help?

Comment: Please give me an explanation?

Comment: My teacher said 4 in class.but how? This is my home assignment.so please help if you can

Comment: Well, do you know how to calculate $$\dim U,  \dim W$$ and $$\dim (U \cap W) $$. If not, what do you not understand?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate $$dim(U\cap W) $$

Comment: $$U \cap W = \{(a,b,c,d) \mid b+c+d=0, a+b=0, c=2d \} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension of $U$ is $3$, and the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $4$, hence there are no spaces strictly between $U$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Clearly, $U \subseteq U+W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$, so the dimension of $U+W$ is $3$ or $4$, according as $U+W=U$, or $U+W=\mathbb{R}^4$.

But $U+W = U$ if and only if $W \subseteq U$, which is not the case, since, for example, the vector $(a,b,c,d) = (1,-1,2,1)$ is in $W$, but not in $U$.

Therefore $U+W = \mathbb{R}^4$, so has dimension $4$.